# Greendao Autoincrement inserting record not working

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

I am using greendao 3.2 and making Entities and database. Its all working fine. 
But I am having trouble when creating Id property that must be Auto increment. I know How to do it in SQL but using greendao its giving me much more tough time.

I have declared my entities as normal. let me give you example.

```
@Entity
public class User {

// this will make your id autoincremented
@org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Id (autoincrement = true)
private Long Id;
private String name;
@Generated(hash = 690585871)
public User(Long Id, String name) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.name = name;
}
@Generated(hash = 586692638)
public User() {
}
public Long getId() {
    return this.Id;
}
public void setId(Long Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

and inserting values like

```
user = new User();
    user.setName("Hello Green Dao");
    Long id = userDao.insertOrReplace(user);
```

but its overlapping record again and again with Id 0. Its not working as expected.

please tell me what is the reason. I have tried using Insert also but it is showing same results. Please help I am stuck into it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used it as below and it is working fine.

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "cities")
public class City {
  @Id(autoincrement = true)
  private Long id;
  ....
}
```

The only difference is that you used `Id`, maybe using it with capital `I` made it kind of reserved word and cause this problem. Or maybe you should brief the annotation above it to `@Id` instead of full package path. I know this all sounds weird, but it worth to try.

Comment: returning 0 means it doesn't inserted, did you tried querying the entity and find out if it is inserted?

Comment: yes it is inserted. for example its insert one record , and on inserting other it replaces the first one

Comment: @Androidteem was it the name of `Id` filed and you have to make it all lowercase?

Comment: it is recommended to use Long

Comment: @Androidteem yes, I mean the name of field not the type.

Comment: I have solved my problem my making some checks in the relative daos. But I am facing new problem and that is , my custom code in dao gets deletes when I run generator for any changes in any other entities. Please help me. here is the question link I posted :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003685/dao-generator-pitfall

Comment: what changes you have to add in your `dao` ? you shouldn't change `dao` manually, you have to change your models and its annotations so as the right `dao` object generated.

Comment: I was not getting autoincrement itself, I changed dao as suggested by @shararti KAKA check his answer you will get it what I changed

Comment: clean your project and delete all codes generated by greenDao in your model and then run gradle build so as they recreated again. Then check if dao is correct or not. I guess it will be ok then.

Comment: no , I am using generator. Not this method as you said to build the project. to create daos i have to run the generator.

Comment: @Androidteem if my suggested solution worked, please make my answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out checking this functionality. Please check the dao

```
public class UserDao extends AbstractDao<User, Long> {

public static final String TABLENAME = "USER";

/**
 * Properties of entity User.<br/>
 * Can be used for QueryBuilder and for referencing column names.
 */
public static class Properties {
    public final static Property Id = new Property(0, Long.class, "Id", true, "_id");
    public final static Property Name = new Property(1, String.class, "name", false, "NAME");
}


public UserDao(DaoConfig config) {
    super(config);
}

public UserDao(DaoConfig config, DaoSession daoSession) {
    super(config, daoSession);
}

/** Creates the underlying database table. */
public static void createTable(Database db, boolean ifNotExists) {
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "\"USER\" (" + //
            "\"_id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," + // 0: Id
            "\"NAME\" TEXT);"); // 1: name
}

/** Drops the underlying database table. */
public static void dropTable(Database db, boolean ifExists) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE " + (ifExists ? "IF EXISTS " : "") + "\"USER\"";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
protected final void bindValues(DatabaseStatement stmt, User entity) {
    stmt.clearBindings();

    Long Id = entity.getId();
    if (Id != null) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, Id);
    }

    String name = entity.getName();
    if (name != null) {
        stmt.bindString(2, name);
    }
}

@Override
protected final void bindValues(SQLiteStatement stmt, User entity) {
    stmt.clearBindings();

    Long Id = entity.getId();
    if (Id != null) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, Id);
    }

    String name = entity.getName();
    if (name != null) {
        stmt.bindString(2, name);
    }
}

@Override
public Long readKey(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
    return cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0);
}    

@Override
public User readEntity(Cursor cursor, int offset) {
    User entity = new User( //
        cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0), // Id
        cursor.isNull(offset + 1) ? null : cursor.getString(offset + 1) // name
    );
    return entity;
}

@Override
public void readEntity(Cursor cursor, User entity, int offset) {
    entity.setId(cursor.isNull(offset + 0) ? null : cursor.getLong(offset + 0));
    entity.setName(cursor.isNull(offset + 1) ? null : cursor.getString(offset + 1));
 }

@Override
protected final Long updateKeyAfterInsert(User entity, long rowId) {
    entity.setId(rowId);
    return rowId;
}

@Override
public Long getKey(User entity) {
    if(entity != null) {
        return entity.getId();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasKey(User entity) {
    return entity.getId() != null;
}

@Override
protected final boolean isEntityUpdateable() {
    return true;
}
```

}

this whole project is found [here](https://github.com/techcamino/GreenDaoDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/techcamino/greendao/demo/database/UserDao.java). I think you need to keep some check like it. in the UserDao.

Answer (score 0):

use Long Instead of long . this work for me